# Why is my EJS view not rendering after using the PUT/update method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Im building a CRUD recipes application using NODE.js and Express. I can currently create a new recipe and delete a recipe, but I am running issues into when it comes to updating a recipe.

Heres my code for my controller, routes, models and view:

```
//controller.js
recipesController.update = (req, res) => {
  Recipes.update({
    recipe : req.body.recipe,
    category: req.body.category,
    area: req.body.area,
    instructions: req.body.instructions,
    ingredients: req.body.ingredients,
    measurement: req.body.measurement,
    img: req.body.img,
    tag: req.body.tag
  }, req.params.id)
  .then(() => {
    res.redirect(`/recipes`)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).json(err)
  });
};
```

These are my routes
    //routes.js

```
recipesRouter.get('/', recipesController.index);
recipesRouter.get('/new', recipesController.new);
recipesRouter.get('/:id', recipesController.show);
recipesRouter.get('/:id/edit', recipesController.edit);
recipesRouter.put('/:id', recipesController.update);
recipesRouter.post('/', recipesController.create);
recipesRouter.delete('/:id', recipesController.delete);
```

This is my models
    //models.js

```
Recipes.update = (recipes, id) => {
  return db.oneOrNone(`
    UPDATE recipes SET
    recipe = $1,
    category = $2,
    area = $3,
    instructions = $4,
    ingredients = $5,
    measurement = $6,
    img = $7,
    tag = $8,
    WHERE id = $9
    `,[recipes.recipe, recipes.category, recipes.area, recipes.instructions, recipes.ingredients, recipes.measurement, recipes.img, recipes.tag, id])
};
```

My views mirror my model(was too long to include).
Thoughts?

Comment: are you sure recipesController.update is calling ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Yes I call it in my routes and have my controller object being exported along with its methods.

Comment: .then((done) => {
console.log("done", done ) 
    res.redirect(`/recipes`)
  }) and tell me whether  done is print  or not.

Comment: ```recipesController.update = (req, res) => {
  Recipes.update({
    recipe : req.body.recipe,
    category: req.body.category,
    area: req.body.area,
    instructions: req.body.instructions,
    ingredients: req.body.ingredients,
    measurement: req.body.measurement,
    img: req.body.img,
    tag: req.body.tag
  }, req.params.id)
    .then((done) => {
      console.log("done", done )
      res.redirect('/recipes')
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).json(err)
  });
};```

Comment: i'm saying call the put request and check whether done pirnt or not ?

Comment: HEYYYY just figured it out. Very silly mistake. In my models.js, there was a comma right after the tag = $8 and thats what threw it off. Once I deleted it it went through. Thanks for your help @shivshankar